# array<String^>^ syntax and String^

Tags: c++-cli

I am analysing C++ project.I found some unknown syntax in project.

```
 array<String^>^ syntax and String^
```

can some please help me to understand these syntax.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx

Comment: I guess you are viewing C++/CLI code, not C++.

Comment: but extension is .cpp only.Still can it be other language(in this case c++/CLI)?

Comment: C++/CLI is a superset of C++03, so yes it uses the same file extension.